# Django CBV Form very Problematic

Tags: python, django

I have a problem with Django CBV. I am unable to render my form on the page. (even if I do, I'm unable to save the form).

I would like to:

1. Show a form (let's call it tweet form), and display all tweets on the same page (using 2 separate views)
2. Save the tweet, and show updated list of tweets on same page.

Below is my code, but it doesn't seem to work:

**forms.py**

```
from django import forms
from .models import Tweet

class TweetForm(forms.Form):
text = forms.CharField(widget=forms.Textarea(attrs={'rows': 1, 'cols': 85}), max_length=155)
country = forms.CharField(widget=forms.HiddenInput())
```

**urls.py**

```
from django.conf.urls import include, url
from django.contrib import admin
from microblog.views import Index, Profile, PostTweet

admin.autodiscover()

urlpatterns = [
url(r'^$', Index.as_view(), name='home'), # Homepage of app
url(r'^user/(\w+)/$', Profile.as_view(), name='profile'), # User profile page
url(r'^user/(\w+)/post/$', PostTweet.as_view(), name='post'),
url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
]
```

**views.py**

```
class Profile(View):
    def get(self, request, username):
        params = dict()
        user = User.objects.get(username=username)
        tweets = Tweet.objects.filter(user=user)
        params["tweets"] = tweets
        params["user"] = user
        return render(request, 'microblog/profile.html', params)

class PostTweet(View):
    def post(self, request, username):
        form = TweetForm(self.request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            user = User.objects.get(username=username)
            tweet = Tweet(text=form.cleaned_data['text'], user=user, country=form.cleaned_data['country'])
            tweet.save()
            words = form.cleaned_data['text'].split(" ")
            for word in words:
                if word[0] == "#":
                    hashtag, created = HashTag.objects.get_or_create(name=word[1:])
                hashtag.tweet.add(tweet)
         return HttpResponseRedirect('/user/'+username)
```

Any help is appreciated a lot!! I have been breaking my head about this!!

Comment: Please fix your indentation...

Comment: Just fixed my indentation, hope it is more readable now.

Comment: Why don't you use an actual [form view](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/class-based-views/generic-editing/)?

Comment: I am trying out a tutorial from a local book and this is how it's being done. I'm confused as to how to make this work.

Comment: Get another book then. This code can't possibly work.

Comment: If you are using the base 'View', it doesn't implement a post method.  Check out the class based views here https://ccbv.co.uk/ .  Like @DanielRoseman says, you really want a FormView here.  Also, you'll want to send an empty form in your get method, in order to render it on the template. [FormView](https://ccbv.co.uk/projects/Django/1.8/django.views.generic.edit/FormView/) - See the get and post methods

Comment: @DanielRoseman Is it possible to merge a listview and formview to show it on the same page and yet maintain separate views for each?

Comment: You cannot show two views on the same page, period. A URL maps to a single view.